# Modifying the stack on Windows, TIB and exceptions

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, exception, fibers

The origin of my question effectively stems from wanting to provide an implementation of pthreads on Windows which supports user provide stacks.  Specifically, `pthread_attr_setstack` should do something meaningful.  My actual requirements are a bit more involved than this but this is good enough for the purpose of the post.

There are no public Win APIs for providing a stack in either the Fiber or Thread APIs.  I've searched around for sneaky backdoors, workarounds and hacks, there's nothing going.  In fact, I looked that the winpthread source for inspiration and that ignores any stack provided to `pthread_attr_setstack`.

Instead I tried the following "solution" to see if it would work.  I create a Fiber using the usual combination of `ConvertThreadToFiber`, `CreateFiberEx` and `SwitchToFiber`.  In `CreateFiberEx` I provide a minimal stack size.  In the entry point of the fibre I then allocate memory for a stack, change the TIB fields: "Stack Base" and "Stack Limit" appropriately (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) and then set ESP to the high address of my stack.

(In a real world case I would setup the stack better than this and change EIP as well so that this step behaves more like the posix funciton `swapcontext`, but you get the idea).

If I make any OS calls when on this different stack then I'm pretty much screwed (`printf` for example dies).  However this isn't an issue for me.  I can ensure that I never make sure calls when on my custom stack (hence why I said my actual requirements are a bit more involved).  Except...I need exceptions to work. And they don't!  Specifically, if I try to throw and catch an exception on my modified stack then I get an assert

> Unhandled exception at 0xXXXXXXXX ....

So my (vague) question is, does anyone have any insight as to how exceptions and a custom stack might not be playing nicely together?  I appreciate that this is totally unsupported and can happily except nil response or "go away".  In fact, I've pretty much decided that I need a different solution and, despite this involving compromise, I'm likely to use one.  However, curiosity gets the better of me so I'd like to know why this doesn't work.

On a related note, I wondered how Cygwin dealt with this for ucontext.  The source here http://szupervigyor.ddsi.hu/source/in/openjdk-6-6b18-1.8.13/cacao-0.99.4/src/vm/jit/i386/cygwin/ucontext.c uses `GetThreadContext`/`SetThreadContext` to implement ucontext.  However, from experimentation I see that this also fails when an exception is thrown from inside a new context.  In fact the `SetThreadContext` call doesn't even update the TIB block!

**EDIT (based on the answer from @avakar)**

The following code, which is very similar to yours, demonstrates the same failure.  The difference is that I don't start the second thread suspended but suspend it then try to change context.  This code exhibits the error I was describing when the try-catch block is hit in `foo`.  Perhaps this simply isn't legal.  One notable thing is that in this situation the `ExceptionList` member of the TIB is a valid pointer when `modifyThreadContext` is called, whereas in your example it's -1.  Manually editing this doesn't help.

As mentioned in my comment to your answer.  This isn't precisely what I need.  I would like to switch contexts from the thread I'm current on.  However, the docs for `SetThreadContext` warn not to call this on an active thread.  So I'm guessing that if the below code doesn't work then I have no chance of making it work on a single thread.

```
namespace
{
HANDLE ghSemaphore = 0;

void foo()
{
    try
    {
        throw 6;
    }
    catch(...){}

    ExitThread(0);
}

void modifyThreadContext(HANDLE thread)
{
    typedef NTSTATUS WINAPI NtQueryInformationThread_t(HANDLE ThreadHandle, DWORD ThreadInformationClass, PVOID ThreadInformation, ULONG ThreadInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength);

    HMODULE hNtdll = LoadLibraryW(L"ntdll.dll");
    auto NtQueryInformationThread = (NtQueryInformationThread_t *)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "NtQueryInformationThread");

    DWORD stackSize = 1024 * 1024;
    void * mystack = VirtualAlloc(0, stackSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    DWORD threadInfo[7];
    NtQueryInformationThread(thread, 0, threadInfo, sizeof threadInfo, 0);

    NT_TIB * tib = (NT_TIB *)threadInfo[1];

    CONTEXT ctx = {};
    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    GetThreadContext(thread, &ctx);

    ctx.Esp = (DWORD)mystack + stackSize - ((DWORD)tib->StackBase - ctx.Esp);
    ctx.Eip = (DWORD)&foo;
    tib->StackBase = (PVOID)((DWORD)mystack + stackSize);
    tib->StackLimit = (PVOID)((DWORD)mystack);
    SetThreadContext(thread, &ctx);
}

DWORD CALLBACK threadMain(LPVOID)
{
    ReleaseSemaphore(ghSemaphore, 1, NULL);
    while (1)
        Sleep(10000);
    // Never gets here
    return 1;
}
} // namespace

int main()
{
    ghSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, NULL);
    HANDLE th = CreateThread(0, 0, threadMain, 0, 0, 0);

    while (WaitForSingleObject(ghSemaphore, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0);

    SuspendThread(th);

    modifyThreadContext(th);
    ResumeThread(th);

    while (WaitForSingleObject(th, 10) != WAIT_OBJECT_0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exception handling is indeed the problem, you did not setup the NT_TIB.ExceptionList.  A bad problem as well is that you have no decent way to deal with or report stack overflow.  You are just helping entirely too much, a fiber already has a perfectly usable stack.  You asked for it in the CreateFiber() call, the 1st argument sets its size.

Comment: Your comment implies that NT_TIB.ExceptionList can be set at all (at least to something meaningful), is that the case?  I presume this gets set by the thread/fibre entry point, which is of course a closed box.  Btw, I appreciate that the API provides a set way of doing things and, undoubtedly, a good one.  Unfortunately I have requirements which mean that I need to do this.  At least I do until this provably not achievable in any sane way.  In which case it's time for a redesign!

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/overview.html?

Comment: Anyway, it might be better to give us an actual motivation. Helping you solve tiny fragments of your problem will rarely help you reach an optimal solution.

Comment: I'll take a look at the boost context source. And fair point re the motiviation. I was hoping we wouldn't need full details but we're probably at the stage where I should expand so as to save wasted energy.  I'll do some more investigation then add more details.

Answer (score 2):

Both exceptions and `printf` work for me, and I don't see why they shouldn't. If you post your code, we can try to pinpoint what's going on.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD CALLBACK ThreadProc(LPVOID)
{
    try
    {
        throw 1;
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}

typedef NTSTATUS WINAPI NtQueryInformationThread_t(HANDLE ThreadHandle, DWORD ThreadInformationClass, PVOID ThreadInformation, ULONG ThreadInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength);

int main()
{
    HMODULE hNtdll = LoadLibraryW(L"ntdll.dll");
    auto NtQueryInformationThread = (NtQueryInformationThread_t *)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "NtQueryInformationThread");

    DWORD stackSize = 1024 * 1024;
    void * mystack = VirtualAlloc(0, stackSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, &ThreadProc, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &dwThreadId);

    DWORD threadInfo[7];
    NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, 0, threadInfo, sizeof threadInfo, 0);

    NT_TIB * tib = (NT_TIB *)threadInfo[1];

    CONTEXT ctx = {};
    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);

    ctx.Esp = (DWORD)mystack + stackSize - ((DWORD)tib->StackBase - ctx.Esp);
    tib->StackBase = (PVOID)((DWORD)mystack + stackSize);
    tib->StackLimit = (PVOID)((DWORD)mystack);
    SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);

    ResumeThread(hThread);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Very useful as this might be all I actually need to make things work (although I need to go away and experiment with a few things).  Also, I didn't know there was a "supported" way to get the TIB.  I was just querying the segment register fs in assembly to get the TIB and manually editing it!  So another useful tip.

Comment: I've modified my code to be more like yours for discussion.  I can confirm this works as is, but the problem for me is two fold.  Firstly, in general I need the current thread to be able to change it's own context (like swapcontext would do).  I tried this, even with mods similar to yours, and I get the same problem.  I then tried with multithreaded code like yours and still get a problem *if* the thread already starts then suspends.  I'll paste that code in my original qn and discuss there as I'm running out of chara....